# Creating custom keyboard shortcuts in a linux c application

Tags: c, linux, keyboard, shortcut

I am trying to handle keyboard shortcuts, I already know how to do it with signals but the problem is that the signal list doesn't offer a lot of choices.
So I was wondering if it was possible to handle shortcuts like <kbd>CTRL+'key'</kbd> 
and `key` can be any keyboard key like `A Z E R T Y`.

Comment: Use GNU `readline`. Read the docs about custom functions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using GNU [**`readline`**](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html). You can capture key sequences <kbd>Ctrl+P</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+G</kbd>, etc.

```
int keyPressed(int count, int key) {

        printf("key pressed: %d\n",key);
        rl_on_new_line();
        return 0;
}

int main() {
        rl_catch_signals = 0;
        rl_bind_keyseq("\\C-g",keyPressed);
        rl_bind_keyseq("\\C-p",keyPressed);
        rl_bind_keyseq("\\C-z",keyPressed);

        while(1) {
                char *line = readline("rl> ");
        }
```

For [special characters](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Special-Characters.html#Special-Characters) such as signal characters, <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> you will need `rl_catch_signals=0`. This way, you can define your own signal handlers.

One thing I found is that `rl_bind_keyseq("\\C-z",keyPressed)` will not be called, even if you put the terminal in `raw` mode before calling `readline`. Instead the terminal will still interpret <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> as `SIGTSTP`.

Looking through the source code, it's apparent that every time `readline()` is called, the terminal settings are [reset](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC38).

```
//rltty.c
    #if defined (HANDLE_SIGNALS)
      tiop->c_lflag &= ~ISIG;
    #else
      tiop->c_lflag |= ISIG;
    #endif
```

Unless you want to modify `readline`, I suggest defining signal handlers for special characters.